# How to install driver for an Acer OrbiCam bison?

Tags: 10.10, webcam

How to install driver acer OrbiCam bison in Ubuntu 10.10?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like OrbiCam worked in ubuntu 10.4 and then stopped working in 10.10. This bug has history back to karmic 9.10.

Last bug report is from 2010-10-10:

> worked on 10.04 stopped working on 10.10 the system can't find a dev/video2 device.
>   stil with lsusb I get
>    Bus 001 Device 012: ID 046d:0896 Logitech, Inc. OrbiCam

Check [THIS](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/271258) bug report for more info.